# Socat not closing tcp connection

Tags: tcp, sockets, socat, alpine-linux

I use `socat 1.7.3.1-r0` and run following command on an `alpine 3.3` linux server:

```
socat -d -d -d PTY,link=/dev/ttyFOOBAR,echo=0,raw,unlink-close=0 TCP-LISTEN:7000,forever,reuseaddr
```

`Socat` will listen for clients and create a bidirectional communication by passing data from the virtual serial port `/dev/ttyFOOBAR` to the client and back again over TCP. Once the client disconnects `socat` should exit.

When such a connection is established socat logs the following:

> ```
> I socat by Gerhard Rieger - see www.dest-unreach.org
> I This product includes software developed by the OpenSSL Project for use in the OpenSSL Toolkit. (http://www.openssl.org/)
> I This product includes software written by Tim Hudson (tjh@cryptsoft.com)
> I setting option "symbolic-link" to "/dev/ttyFOOBAR"
> I setting option "echo" to 0
> I setting option "raw"
> I setting option "unlink-close" to 0
> I openpty({5}, {6}, {"/dev/pts/3"},,) -> 0
> N PTY is /dev/pts/3
> I setting option "forever" to 1
> I setting option "so-reuseaddr" to 1
> I socket(2, 1, 6) -> 7
> I starting accept loop
> N listening on AF=2 0.0.0.0:7000
> I accept(7, {2, AF=2 CLIENT_IP:PORT}, 16) -> 8
> N accepting connection from AF=2 CLIENT_IP:PORT on AF=2 172.20.0.2:7000
> I permitting connection from AF=2 CLIENT_IP:PORT
> I close(7)
> I resolved and opened all sock addresses
> N starting data transfer loop with FDs [5,5] and [8,8]
> ```

`ss` command on the server prints:

```
Netid  State      Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address:Port                 Peer Address:Port                
tcp    ESTAB      0      0      172.20.0.2:7000                 CLIENT_IP:PORT
```

The problem is, that when I disconnect the client (by switching it off), the tcp connection is still established and no addition logging is coming from socat. `ss` still shows the connection as ESTAB. Any ideas why? When I again connect the client following appears in the logs:

```
W read(8, 0x7fa8f48c4020, 8192): Connection reset by peer
N socket 2 to socket 1 is in error
N socket 2 (fd 8) is at EOF
I poll timed out (no data within 0.500000 seconds)
I close(5)
I shutdown(8, 2)
I shutdown(8, 2): Socket not connected
N exiting with status 0
```

But why does this happen on connect instead of disconnect?

Comment: Crosslink for future reference: looks like OP crossposted this on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36575588/5267751)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you shut the client off, it has no opportunity to tell the other side that it's going away. The only way to tell that the peer is gone is to try sending something to it and noticing that it doesn't respond.

If it is a requirement in your application that a dead peer be detected, you'll have to implement dead peer detection. You can do this by enabling the `keepalive` option in `socat`, but that can still take several hours to detect a dead peer. You can also do this by sending something periodically -- the send will time out if the peer is dead, triggering detection. If the other side is supposed to be sending data to you, you can abort if you haven't received the data you're expecting (perhaps with `socat`'s `-T` flag).